# Eliminate all identifiers if atleast one condition is not satisfied

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three columns: identifier, driver_id, driver_id_was

My condition is to eliminate those identifiers which always had driver_id and driver_ids_was as -1.

But my current query is doing the opposite.It is including all identifiers which has driver_id and driver_id_was as -1 at least once.

```
SELECT identifier
        ,model
        ,sw_pkg_version
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN driver_id_was != -1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "count_driver_id_was_not"
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN driver_id_was = -1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "count_driver_id_was"
        ,COUNT(CA

 FROM eld_messages
 WHERE model LIKE '%ca'
       AND created_at > getdate()-30
 GROUP BY identifier
          ,driver_id_was
          ,model
          ,sw_pkg_version
          ,driver_id
 HAVING count_driver_id_was_not = 0
    AND count_driver_id_was > 0;
```

Comment: I don’t get it , why is not driver_id and driver_id_was part of the WHERE condition then? Maybe add some sample data to explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have added the condition in having clause.

Comment: Can you add sample data and the desired result?

Comment: What is COUNT(CA?. And I don't think you should have driver_id_was in the group by.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your question is hard to follow.  You mention a table with three columns, but then have a query that references many more.  Your query is not valid SQL syntax, and it includes logic not mentioned in the question.  Sample data and desired results help.

Comment: @Ron Any feedback on the answers given or the questions asked in the comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My condition is to eliminate those identifiers which always had driver_id and driver_ids_was as -1.

Is this what you want?

```
select identifier
from eld_messages
group by identifier
having sum(case when count_driver_id_was_not <> -1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when count_driver_id_was <> -1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Or, similarly but more succinctly:

```
select distinct identifier
from eld_messages
where count_driver_id_was_not <> -1 or count_driver_id_was <> -1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand the question but it’s hard to be sure without sample data or further clarification. Maybe this answer will generate some response.

```
SELECT identifier
    ,model
    ,sw_pkg_version
FROM eld_messages
WHERE model LIKE '%ca'
  AND created_at > getdate()-30
  AND driver_id <> -1
  AND driver_id_was <> -1
```